# Windows having 'transparent borders'

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, windows-10

I'm moving around windows using 'MoveWindow' (user32.dll) and have some weird problem: If I place two windows right next to each other, there appears to be a small spacing between them, even though their positions should fit! I already found a discussion on this problem on [msdn](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150304-00/?p=44543), and the border appears to be 7 pixels (only in Windows 10!).

Here is a small example using 3 cmd.exe:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

// ...

MoveWindow(new IntPtr(6488704), 0, 0, 200, 100, true);
MoveWindow(new IntPtr(16975898), 200, 0, 200, 100, true);
MoveWindow(new IntPtr(1050266), 0, 100, 200, 100, true);
```

Of course I could just place the windows 7 pixels off the original position and make the borders disappear. But here's the problem: It looks like the borders are different for different applications. So that way, some applications are just fine and others overlap, because the border is just 5 pixels or something.

Is there a way to find the actual position / size of a window? And then calculate the 'transparent borders'? I'm really lost here and can't find anything on the internet. I also don't understand why there even is a transparent border at all.

Comment: In Windows 10 `MoveWindow` is working correctly if you consider that the transparent borders are just part of the window. To fix this non-error the way you have proposed, you actually have to move the window to the wrong position. I suggest you leave it as is. Another option is to use border-less windows, or override `WM_NCPAINT` and paint the borders a certain color, to make it look like Windows 8 (not really a good option)

Comment: Use `DwmGetWindowAttribute(hwnd, DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS, ...)` to get the rendered rectangle (as opposed to the logical rectangle).

Comment: DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS is basically what I need, but it returns the exact same position and size as getwindowrect. Even more strange is, that while I'm dragging the window to another position, it shows the smaller size. When releasing the mouse, the "wrong" size is shown again. Is there another option to geht the "actual" size?